# Using custom normals instead of generated normals in calculations

Tags: python, normals, freestyle

I'm currently in the process of creating some very unique to say the least code for the freestyle render engine.  Everything has been progressing smoothly so far, but I've hit a roadblock due to not knowing how to incorporate Blender's custom built-in modules into my code.

The main issue I'm facing revolves around my code not incorporating my object's custom normals into its calculation for its normals.
Here's a brief summary of the issue I'm facing:

In Freestyle, there are two methods for calculating normals. The first method is a built-in method from the render engine, however this method doesn't use the objects in the scene to calculate normals. Instead, it uses a view map of the render, which is basically just a fancy height map. Therefore, custom normals cannot be used, since the render engine doesn't account for them and instead generates its own.

However, i noticed there is a second method the freestyle render engine can use to calculate normals and this is by using the built-in (mathutils) modules in Blender. This is a step in the right direction since it uses an object's vector to calculate normals, instead of the view map. However, it still doesn't account for custom normals, which was incredibly disappointing to find out.

I'm very new to Python programming in Blender, and I'm unsure about how to implement custom normals into the code. However, I have a strong feeling that it can be done. Freestyle uses mathutils.vector to generate the normals, and I'm wondering how I could modify this example code or create a new code to take custom normals into account. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Also, the NormalThresholdShader class is just a placeholder, so there's no need to worry about errors coming from that section. I just need to know is how to use an object's custom normals in the code, not if it works with my custom styles modules. Many thanks!

```
from freestyle.predicates import *
from freestyle.shaders import *
from freestyle.types import *
from freestyle.functions import *
from _freestyle import * 
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
from math import cos, sin, pi, atan2
from mathutils import Color

# Normal calculation stuff

def normal_at_I0D(it: Interface0DIterator) -> Vector:
    """Normal at an Interface0D object. In contrast to Normal2DF0D this
       function uses the actual data instead of underlying Fedge objects.
    """
    if it.at_last and it.is_begin:
        # corner-case
        return Vector((0, 0))
    elif it.at_last:
        it.decrement()
        a, b = it.object, next(it)
    elif it.is_begin:
        a, b = it.object, next(it)
        # give iterator back in original state
        it.decrement()
    elif it.is_end:
        # just fail hard: this should not happen
        raise StopIteration()
    else:
        # this case sometimes has a small difference with Normal2DF0D (1e-3 -ish)
        it.decrement()
        a = it.object
        _curr, b = next(it), next(it)
        # give iterator back in original state
        it.decrement()
    return (b.point - a.point).orthogonal().normalized()


def angle_x_normal(it: Interface0DIterator):
    """Unsigned angle between a Point's normal and the X axis, in radians"""
    normal = normal_at_I0D(it)
    return abs(atan2(normal[1], normal[0]))


# Color based on an input threshold on the calculated normal

class NormalThresholdShader(StrokeShader):
   def __init__(self, threshold):
       StrokeShader.__init__(self)
       self.threshold = threshold

   def shade(self, stroke):
       it = stroke.stroke_vertices_begin()
       for svert in it:
           angle = angle_x_normal(it)
           if angle > self.threshold:
               color = Color((0, 128, 0))
           else:
               color = Color((48, 0, 48))
           svert.attribute.color = color


# Selection operators

upred = QuantitativeInvisibilityUP1D(0)
Operators.select(upred)

# Shaders

shaders_list = [NormalThresholdShader(.7)]

# Creation operators

Operators.create(TrueUP1D(), shaders_list)
```